# Showing ValueError: shapes (1,2) and (3,1) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to run this code, and the prediction model (predictions = model.predict(y1)) shows an error as suggested in the heading. I am new to the area, any help is appreciated?

```
from sklearn import linear_model
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

import seaborn as seabornInstance 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 

from sklearn import metrics


x1 = np.asanyarray(train[['MachineAvailability','StatNumIn','MachineMTTR']])
y1 = np.asanyarray(train[['StatNumOut']])
regr.fit (x1, y1)
# The coefficients
print ('Coefficients: ', regr.coef_)
print('Intercept: \n', regr.intercept_)

y_hat= regr.predict(test[['MachineAvailability','StatNumIn','MachineMTTR']])
x = np.asanyarray(test[['MachineAvailability','StatNumIn','MachineMTTR']])
y = np.asanyarray(test[['StatNumOut']])
print("Residual sum of squares: %.2f"
      % np.mean((y_hat - y) ** 2))

# Explained variance score: 1 is perfect prediction
print('Variance score: %.2f' % regr.score(x, y))

import tkinter as tk 
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

X = sm.add_constant(x1) # adding a constant

model = sm.OLS(x1, y1).fit()

predictions = model.predict(y1) 

# prediction with sklearn
New_MachineAvailability = 90
#New_StatNumIn = 90
New_MachineMTTR = 20
print ('Predicted Production: \n', regr.predict([[New_MachineMTTR,New_MachineAvailability ]]))
```

Comment: I have managed to sort it out. this is what I did, it was straightforward.

Comment: # prediction with sklearn
New_MachineAvailability = 100
New_MachineMTTR = 0
New_StatNumIn= 17
print ('Predicted StatNumOut: \n', regr.predict([[New_MachineAvailability ,New_MachineMTTR,New_StatNumIn]]))

Comment: Your code should be failing on `predictions = model.predict(y1) `, so a few lines before the one you mentioned in the comment. Was my answer helpful? It exactly discusses the shape problem. Check the https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and welcome to the community.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you everything there's to know: the shape of the input to the `predict` function does not match what is expected.

You have trained your model on input data that has shape of `x1`, say `(n, k)`, where `n` is number of rows (axis 0) and `k` number of columns (axis 1). That means input to the `predict` function must match the expected shape in terms of number of columns, i.e. `(m, k)`. There can be any number of rows (it does not matter, it's just number of samples), but same number of columns `k`.

In your case you run the `predict` with `y1`, which is label (target) for the model. It has different shape and likely that's not what you meant. If you pass `x1` it will work, but will have little sense - `x1` was your training data. You should put aside some data for testing, say `x2`, on which you can run prediction and evaluate how model performed.